# Troubleshooting Kibana Dashboard Configuration for Metricbeat Modules

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, monitoring, elastic-stack, metricbeat

How can I configure Kibana to display monitoring dashboards for the PostgreSQL and System modules when I've already set up these modules in the Metricbeat configuration file (metricbeat.yml )? While I can see that Elasticsearch and Logstash dashboards are visible in Kibana, and I've verified that the PostgreSQL and System data are successfully indexed (as observed in the metricbeat logs and Elasticsearch indices), the corresponding dashboards for these modules are not showing up. What could be the reason and how can I resolve this issue?